# EJS file not rendering stylesheet despite feeding from template partial

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am running into a weird issue where my page that is routed to provide additional information about an individual record from my database list on my homepage is not pulling in my stylesheets located in my partial/head, but is passing the object information correctly. I'm not exactly sure why this would be. The specific route not accepting my style information is /blog/:blog_id.

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

//index 
router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));

    router.route('/') 

        // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Blog created.' });
                });

        }) // END POST method


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {

                if (err) return next(err)

                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);

                        blogpost.title = req.body.title; // get the blog title
                        blogpost.author = req.body.author; // get the author name
                        blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // get tagline
                        blogpost.content = req.body.content; // get the blog content
                        blogpost.category = req.body.category; // get the category
                        blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // get the tags
                        blogpost.date = req.body.date; // get the date of the post

                        res.format({
                            html: function() {
                                res.render('pages/index', {
                                    blogpost: blogpost,
                                    pageCount: pageCount,
                                    itemCount: itemCount
                                })
                            },
                            json: function() {

                                res.json({
                                    object: 'blogpost',
                                    has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                    data: blogpost
                                })
                            }
                        }); // END res.format(html, json)
            }); // END Blogpost.paginate
        }); // END GET method


    //Route for individual blogs
    router.route('/blog/:blogpost_id')


    // START GET method blog by ID  
    .get(function(req, res) {


        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            //res.json(blogpost);
            res.render('pages/blogpost', {
                blogpost: blogpost
            });
        });
    }) // END GET method blog by ID

    // START PUT method
    .put(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // update the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // update the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // update the category 
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; //update the tags
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // update the date of the post


            blogpost.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);


                res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
            });

        });

    }) // END PUT method

    // START DELETE method
    .delete(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.remove({
            _id: req.params.blogpost_id

        }, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });



//about
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/about');
    });

//resume
    router.get('/resume', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/resume');
    });



module.exports = router;
```

partial/head.ejs:

```
<title>Page - Title | Example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/simplegrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
```

pages/blogpost.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div class="blog-content">
                <h1><%= blogpost.title %></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Picture of comparison:

Style found when generating any of my routes besides /blog/:blog_id

[image: Style on every page.]

Style found when generating my /blog/:blog_id route.

[image: No style found for individual blogposts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepend your stylesheets with `/`.

Imagine you're at the URL `localhost/blog/test`, the browser will be looking for the stylesheets at `localhost/blog/test/stylesheets/styles.css`.

By adding a `/` you're serving them from the root, `localhost/stylesheets/styles.css`